# How can I fix blurry content when using CSS transforms?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm designing contact form using CSS and JavaScript. I have found a good example on CodePen. But its contact form is getting blurry. I have used `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` but it didn't fix the problem. Can anyone help me?

This is the link to the CodePen example:

[example](http://codepen.io/bleepbloop/pen/nlGzI)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
.envelope {
  …
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]